# What am I doing wrong with my discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am writing my first discord bot with help from a tutorial. I am stuck because my bot hasn't been able to respond to commands and I've checked the tutorials and my code many times over. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
const discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new discord.Client();

const prefix = '!';


client.once('ready' , () => {
  console.log('Zach Is Bad is online');
});


client.on('message', message =>{
  if (!message.content.startswith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if(command === 'ping'){
    message.channel.send('pong!');
  }
});


client.login('redacted')
```

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive; `startswith` should be `startsWith`.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue with your code is `message.content.startswith(prefix)`.

It is startsWith, it's case sensitive.

```js
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo at `client.on('ready', () => ...)`, but this shouldn't be the cause of the error.

You wrote `if (!message.content.startswith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;` but I'm pretty sure `startwith` must be `startWith` (caps are importants). Try modifying this, then restart your bot.

If it doesn't work put `console.log("test OK")` right before the ping command, restart and send `!ping`. If there is "test OK" in your bot logs, then the problem come from the ping command. If you doesn't see this log, try moving the `console.log` line before the if statement. This is a simple yet effective method to know where does a problem come from.

Comment: What typo are you talking about? The `once` event listener is a [valid listener function](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_eventname_listener)